why an responsive image is shrinking inside flex container and not taking up whole space on responsive screen sizes?
i want to prevent the image from shrinking inside the flexbox, leaving so much space inside the flex container. In fact, the image is made responsive using the img-fluid class from bootstrap 5 classes. It looks fine on a large screen,but when the screen size is reduced, the image becomes small inside the container.

I tried somany ways to sort it out.But i dont know whether its because of not using right image size or beacause i need to correct it for different screens using media queries.

Post your html and css code too, just screenshot doesn't help.

I don't know if i understand correctly, but if you want your image to not shrink when your page becomes small, you can remove the img-fluid on the image.
Also, if you want your image to stay in your flexbox container when your page is small (need the class= img-fluid) you can use this class : <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly (use the image folder name here)">
You can find more on the Boostrap website for the class i posted: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/
Last solution if you want your img-fluid to remain, i would suggest to make a class in your CSS file with a minimum for your images so they dont shrink to much when your window becomes small.
(Forgot to mention, use !important after min-width and min-height so it can take precedence over Bootstrap styles).

you gave me three solutions.I tried all and here are the results:
(1) removing .img-fuid made my image overflow the flexcontainer.so it didnt work for me. (2)d-flex justify-content-evenly -in that solution i didnt understand what u mean by "(use the image folder here)"-so i didnt try (3)min-width and min-height didnt give any effect in the result-it didnt work for me

But i think of a solution is using mediaqueries.Changing fontsize in small screens, so that flex container wont stretch vertically in small screens in first place making image look smaller.And in very small screens just that image is displayed in full width (ie col-md-12).so there is no issue in very small screens.So,i think basically a little code in mediaqueries will make my image responsive.There may be some alternatives way.But i cant find anything which worked for me until now.

Thankyou for giving me a reply.
